# In Python is there a better way to assign the first result from lxml xpath()?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm working on converting some of my scripts that transform XML documents from Perl to Python.

In Perl using XML::LibXML I can do

`my ($target) = $dom->findnodes('/root/child1');`

to assign the first node from the nodelist that is returned.

In Python so far I got this to work:

`target = (tree.xpath('/root/child1'))[0]`

but I'm wondering if there is a better or more Python like way to do this.

Comment: If your Python version is recent enough you can use `target, *_ = tree.xpath('/root/child1')` but I don't know if this is really better in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a normal and reasonable way to do it (except get rid of the unneeded parenthesis). Its common to do the selection in xpath as much as possible so that `lxml` doesn't have to create extra objects,

```
target = tree.xpath('/root/child1[1]')[0]
```

or to skip the root specification assuming you are already at the root level of the document

```
target = tree.xpath('child1[1]')[0]
```

but I think the most common option is to use the `find` method instead.

```
target = tree.find('child1')
```

`find` is from the `ElementTree` API and uses `ElementPath` instead of `XPath` (they are very similar). It finds the first matching element and returns. `ElementPath` has other methods like `iterfind` for handling large documents.

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain that there's always going to be one and only one `child1` node under `root`, you can assign the first item of the returning list from the `xpath` method directly into a variable by using [iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
target, = tree.xpath('/root/child1')
```

Or if there can possibly be more than one `child1` node under `root` in your input, you can use a starred expression to unpack the rest of the matching nodes into an unused variable, typically named `_` by convention:

```
target, *_ = tree.xpath('/root/child1')
```

Iterable unpacking is generally considered more Pythonic than specifying list items via indices unless you need to specify directly an item at an arbitrary index.